# Assign the static ip-address to my wireless computer

Tags: windows-8, wireless-networking, static-ip

My goal is to assign the static ip-address to my wireless computer.
I'm running windows 8.1.
 I'm following this post:- [How to Assign a Static IP Address in Windows 7, 8, 10, XP, or Vista](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/19249/how-to-assign-a-static-ip-address-in-xp-vista-or-windows-7/)

I did everything as they tell me, and now I came a little issue, I couldn't figure it out why.

Here is my settings

[image]

---

As soon as I hit OK, I won't be able to go to the internet anymore. 
Under my network name, showing the word **limited**

[image]

---

How do I configure this properly ?

Comment: Is your routers address `192.168.1.1`?

Comment: I am completely noob, I hope you don't mind teach me how to check that.

Comment: My default gateway is `10.0.0.1` when I run `ipconfig`

Comment: Should I place that in my Default Gateway column instead ?

Comment: Should I place my static IP start with `10.` rather than `192.` ?

Comment: Go back to automatic assignment, and report your IP, gateway's, and subnet mask. You might be on a MAN/WAN network.

Comment: If a `10.` is being shown when doing `ipconfig`, configuring your PC with a `192.` would be putting it on a different network. Like SalvoF said, go back to auto assignment, then run `ipconfig` and report your IP address, Default Gateway, and DNS servers. Once you configure your static IP, you should go into your wireless router settings and remove that IP from the DHCP pool.

Comment: What is automatic assignment ? What do you guys mean by report ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said in your comment, your default gateway is 10.0.0.1, meaning you're on a `10` private IP range, instead of the `192` range. This is fine, and the `10` range is the default on some routers, most notably on CISCO routers.

**So let's begin.**

Let's start by going back to the automatic assignment: *(Credits to SalvoF and DrZoo)*
[image]

**NOTE:** You do not have to change the DNS to automatic. Only the IP.

Now you can run `ipconfig` once you get a connection. (Let the `cmd` window stay up, don't close it yet).
So now your router's DHCP assigned you a new IP, because you set it to do so automatically and you should see an IP in the `10` range.

Let's go back to assigning the IP address in the properties (how you did previously in your screenshot). Basically, setting it to a `10` range. For example, `10.0.1.1`. for the IP and `255.255.0.0` for the Subnet mask. (Look back at your previous `ipconfig` in the `cmd` window and refer to how it was set up there.)

Now go to your router's settings. (either by navigating to 10.0.0.1 in your browser or however the manufacturer suggests you do. You can google this part). Now as DrZoo mentioned, you should remove the static IP that you set yourself, from the DHCP pool. Again, this is specific to the router and might need to be google'd on how it's done for your particular router.

Removing an IP from the DHCP pool simply means the router won't even try to assign that to a computer that has the properties as "Obtain an IP address automatically". Which means there won't be any IP related conflicts on your network.